# Does Linux IOnice affect /dev/ nodes?

Tags: linux, driver, nice

I've written virtual input drivers for Linux, and a server that communicates with them via /dev nodes.
Now, one of them is a virtual mouse and it's quite important that what the signal server receives gets to the driver as soon as possible for the mouse to feel smooth.

For that reason I set ionice for the server process to 1 (still not to get priority over important linux daemons):

```
    if (ioprio_set(IOPRIO_WHO_PROCESS,getpid(), 1 | IOPRIO_CLASS_RT << IOPRIO_CLASS_SHIFT) == -1) {
        logger->error("ioprio_set() error",errno);
    }
```

But I'm not certain that it even is worth it. Difference, even if any, is not noticable. Are the character special files in /dev/ considered when it comes to I/O priority, despite that no access to the actual disk is given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the layer in the OS that `ionice` affects is the I/O scheduler. At least up to kernel 2.6.17, `cfq` was the only scheduler to actually support `ionice` and I believe nothing has changed, at least with regard to the default schedulers the kernel provides.

I/O schedulers are only used with block devices, where it is possible to queue operations or change their order, delay or merge them etc. (see [here](http://www.wlug.org.nz/LinuxIoScheduler) for example). This is also in line with the fact that you can change the scheduler via `/sys` virtual filesystem for block devices only (files such as `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/queue/scheduler`). Your mouse driver is a character device and as such, it is not at all influenced by the I/O scheduler or `ionice`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you :) I've missed the part about 'block devices' earlier